# Remove special character from property of a javascript object in an array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a simple javascript array of objects like this:

```
  $scope.dataList = [];
                var obj = { "SLicenseNo": "NM-2136", "SBusinessnameLegal": "Luxury Auto Mall of Sioux Falls, Inc.", "SNameFirstSoleproprietor": "Edward"};
                $scope.dataList.push(obj);
```

My dataList array has hundreds of such objects. I want to remove the comma from the SBusinessnameLegal property or any other property that may have a comma. I would like to replace it by a space

So my end object would be something like

```
 obj = { "SLicenseNo": "NM-2136", "SBusinessnameLegal": "Luxury Auto Mall of Sioux Falls Inc.", "SNameFirstSoleproprietor": "Edward"};
```

I have tried converting the array to a json string then .replace(',', ' ');

But that isnt working. Any ideas or pointers on how I can pass an array to a function and it would strip a particular character from all properties of objects in the array ? TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try any of these scenarios :**

- for single object having multiple properties with comma`(,)`

```js
var obj = { 
    "SLicenseNo": "NM-2136", 
    "SBusinessnameLegal": "Luxury Auto Mall of Sioux Falls, Inc.",
    "SNameFirstSoleproprietor": "Edward"
};

var newObj = {};
for (var i in obj) {
  newObj[i] = obj[i].replace(',','');
}

console.log(newObj);
```

- For `array of objects` try this.

```js
var dataList = [
{ 
    "SLicenseNo": "NM-2136", 
    "SBusinessnameLegal": "Luxury Auto Mall of Sioux Falls, Inc.",
    "SNameFirstSoleproprietor": "Edward"
},{ 
    "SLicenseNo": "NM-2136, Test", 
    "SBusinessnameLegal": "Luxury Auto, Mall of Sioux Falls Inc.",
    "SNameFirstSoleproprietor": "Edward"
}];

dataList.map(function(item) {
  var keyse = Object.keys(item);
  for (var i in keyse) {
    item[keyse[i]] = item[keyse[i]].replace(',','');
  }
});

console.log(dataList);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach( function(key){ obj[key] = obj[key].replace(/,/g, " ") } );
```

If you have this in an array then

```
$scope.dataList = $scope.dataList.map( function( obj ){
  Object.keys(obj).each( function(key){ obj[key] = obj[key].replace(/,/g, " ") } );
  return obj;
});
```

Comment: i believe the fuction name is forEach, not each.